# How to pass RECT in COM

Tags: c#, c++, com

I need to get a RECT from COM to C# in 64 bits, so I defined a simple method in IDL as:

```
[id(23), helpstring("method GetRect")] HRESULT GetRect([out,retval] RECT* pRect);
```

and implemented in C++ as

```
STDMETHODIMP CSpot::GetRect(RECT* pRect)
{
CRect rec = get_position(); 
*pRect = rec;
return S_OK;
}
```

I called in C# as:

```
tagRECT rec = pSpot.GetRect();
```

Most time is OK, but sometimes I get 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.

in line:

```
*pRect = rec;
```

What could cause this exception?

Comment: How can you use ``tagRECT rec = pSpot.GetRect();`` when the medhod if defined as ``GetRect(RECT* pRect)``? Shouldn't you use ``pSpot.GetRect(rec)``?

Comment: @fogbit - No, everything is correct here. High level COM wrappers, including `RCW`, often check HRESULT return to generate exceptions for non-`S_OK` results. Argument marked as `[retval]` becomes a return value for such wrapper method. The actual problem here is that the wrapper _sometimes_ passes a zero pointer to the COM method, which causes the exception. Personally I know little about RCW, so I can't say why can such thing happen.

Comment: At a COM interface I would always check the pointer and return E_POINTER on a NULL value. Additionally I would add debug output in the COM server if a NULL value is a contract violation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but when using RECT from COM methods, I need to 'define' the RECT object as following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 0)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```